# Sqlite3 - how to store SELECT values in variables to use outside the connection?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, sqlite, zip

I am trying to use a list to match individual values from a table with each list item, and count each occurrence from another two tables. I think the code I have might explain it better:

```
def info_check():                                                                                                                            
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')                                                                                                    
    c = conn.cursor()                                                                                                                        
    for ind in zip(address, name, number):                                                                                                   
        c.execute('''SELECT * FROM table                                                                                                     
                     WHERE Column4 > Column5                                                                                                 
                       AND Column1 = ?                                                                                                       
                       AND Column2 = ?                                                                                                       
                       AND Column3 = ?''', ind)                                                                                              
        address_found = c.fetchall()                                                                                                         
        if len(address_found) >= 0:                                                                                                          
            for i, j in enumerate(zip(address, name, number)):                                                                               
                if j == ind:                                                                                                                 
                    c.execute('''SELECT * FROM table                                                                                         
                                         WHERE Column4 = Column5                                                                             
                                          AND Column1  = ?                                                                                   
                                          AND Column2 = ?                                                                                    
                                          AND Column3 = ?''', ind)                                                                           
                    name_found = c.fetchall()                                                                                                
                    if len(name_found) >= 0:                                                                                                 
                        for a, b in enumerate(zip(address, name, number)):                                                                   
                            if b == ind:                                                                                                     
                                c.execute('''SELECT * FROM table                                                                             
                                             WHERE Column4 < Column5                                                                         
                                              AND Column1 = ?                                                                                
                                              AND Column2 = ?                                                                                
                                              AND Column3 = ?''', ind)                                                                       
                                number_found = c.fetchall()                                                                                  
                                if len(number_found) >= 2 or len(address_found) >= 2 or len(name_found) >= 2:                                
                                    print(ind)   
                                    print(otherList[i])                                                                                                                      
                                    print(len(address_found), len(name_found), len(number_found))
```

The code works fine, and does what I need, the only problem is that I get duplicates for some of the items, sometimes even 4 results of the same item.

I'm just learning python, and I'm struggling finding a way of removing duplicates from the results.
I'm thinking that if I could store each of the `Select` values, along with their specific `ind` and `i` in variables that I could use outside the `for` loop, maybe that would remove the duplicates? Would have to create a new variable each time for it?

Any help is much appreciated; thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I removed all the unnecessary conditions and did all the `Select` variables first, then only used one `if` containing all variables:

```
def info_check():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    for i, ind in zip(address, name, number):
        c.execute('''SELECT * FROM table
                     WHERE Column4 > Column5
                     AND Column1 = ?
                     AND Column2 = ?
                     AND Column3 = ?''', ind)
        address_found = c.fetchall()
        c.execute('''SELECT * FROM table
                     WHERE Column4 = Column5
                     AND Column1  = ?
                     AND Column2 = ?
                     AND Column3 = ?''', ind)
        name_found = c.fetchall() 
        c.execute('''SELECT * FROM table
                     WHERE Column4 < Column5
                     AND Column1 = ?
                     AND Column2 = ?
                     AND Column3 = ?''', ind)
        number_found = c.fetchall()
        if len(number_found) >= 2 or len(address_found) >= 2 or len(name_found) >= 2:
             print(ind)   
             print(otherList[i])                            
             print(len(address_found), len(name_found), len(number_found))
```